# Detecting smart-contract calls and reacting to 0-conf?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

My question. Let's say I have a contract like 

`contract PowerManager {
    function unlock() { ... }
}`

I want to respond to the `unlock()` function by unlocking an IoT device. Is it possible to detect this in the mempool as soon as it appears?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something you could do with Ethereum Events.

Good overview can be found here:
https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e